# ComponentDidUpdate treates prevState and this.state as equal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, mutation

I have my state which I update with this function:

```
  doChangeValue(data) {
    const dataNew = this.state.data
    dataNew[data.id] = data.value
    this.setState({ ...dataNew, [dataNew[data.id]]: data.value})
  }
```

Which at first looked like this, but that is mutating way to do it as far as I get, so I changed it with the above version:

```
  const dataNew = this.state.data
  dataNew[data.id] = data.value
  this.setState({ data: dataNew })
```

And I have my ComponentDidUpdate:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

    const prev = prevState.data
    const curr = this.state.data
    const isStateChanged = isEqual(prev, curr)

    console.log(isStateChanged);
  }
```

My issue is that both of my variables **prev** and **curr** are always equal, **isStateChanged** - always returns **true**, even when I change the state.

I googled it and the issue seems to be that I reference same object bc my function where I change state is probably mutating it. But now I use spread operator which supposedly doesn't mutate state. So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

doChangeValue in the question is still mutating state. I used Object.assign and it solved the problem. Now whenever I change smthg in my state it shows the difference between prevState and current one:

```
    const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state.data)
    newState[data.id] = data.value
    this.setState({data: newState })
```